# Database query timeout with EF Core 5.0.4

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a SQL Server database with following tables:

- EntryBases, contains transactions info;
- Merchants, contains info about our merchants;
- AccountBases, contains info about merchants' accounts;

Every transaction contains IDs of sender merchant & account and recipient merchant & account.

For report we use following query:

```
        var query =
            from t in _db.EntryBases.AsNoTracking().Where(predicate)
            join accountFromGroupItem in _db.AccountBases.AsNoTracking() on t.AccountFromId equals accountFromGroupItem.Id
                into accountFromGroup
            from accountFrom in accountFromGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join accountToGroupItem in _db.AccountBases.AsNoTracking() on t.AccountToId equals accountToGroupItem.Id
                into accountToGroup
            from accountTo in accountToGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join customerFromGroupItem in _db.Merchants.AsNoTracking() on t.CustomerFromId equals customerFromGroupItem.Id
                into customerFromGroup
            from customerFrom in customerFromGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join customerToGroupItem in _db.Merchants.AsNoTracking() on t.CustomerToId equals customerToGroupItem.Id
                into customerToGroup
            from customerTo in customerToGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { Transaction = t, AccountFrom = accountFrom, AccountTo = accountTo, CustomerFrom = customerFrom, CustomerTo = customerTo };

        var transactions = await query
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Transaction.Id)
            .Skip(filter.Skip.Value)
            .Take(filter.Take.Value)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Because we need some info about sender and recipient in the report. As you see, we use 4 joins here. After transactions counter grew up to 500к we started getting SQL Server timeout exceptions.

So, the problem is to optimize the query for working without timeouts. I see some potential solutions:

1. Enrich EntryBases table with data needed for reporting. But in this case we double data in different tables.
2. Load Merchants and Accounts data in a cache, remove "join"s from query and enrich query received data from cache. But in this case we may have troubles with cache size and its actualization.
3. ??? Another way?

What can you advise?
Thanks for any answers.

Comment: 3. Optimise on the db level (indexes etc).

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy may you recommend some more concrete in my case?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to optimize an EF query when you can't view what part of the query is having issues. If you wrote this query as a view or stored procedure in SQL, then you could view the execution plan and have a chance at optimizing. I recommend moving the query into SQL.

Comment: @Sergey For free I can only recommend to convert your query to t-sql, open it in Query Analyzer and explore the execution plan.

Comment: thanks. it is obvious that the problem is in the "join"s

Comment: Don't you have navigation properties in your model?  Why are you using JOINs?

Comment: I'd run the code with the SQL Profiler recording the session. I'd see what SQL is executed against the database. Most likely as it was said above, the problem is with the indexing strategy, but parameter sniffing might also be a factor. Maybe the problem is with statistics? If a transaction is added to a 500k transaction-long table, it may not trigger statistics recalc.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft no, I don't have. can it speed up search in my case?

Comment: It can simplify your query, and perhaps speed up your seearch.

Comment: i found the bottleneck, the query executes very long if predicate contains text searching like`from t in _db.EntryBases.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Comment.ToUpper().Contains(filter.Comment.ToUpper()))`, any ideas how to speed it up?

Comment: Maybe i should move old transactions to another table (cold storage)? It will allow to speed up an online search on fresh data. But how to prevent the timeout when an user will try to find something in cold storage?

Comment: Try taking out the '.ToUpper()' in your 'Contains'
I believe SQL server queries are case insensitive by default anyway, and I think that may be causing issues